# How to domain mask from one domain to another not under direct control

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

Let's say I have this domain:

https://bananaschool.shop.acme.com

I want to make an alias so it points to:

https://bananaschool.shop.com

or

https://bananachool.com/shop

I own the acme.com and *.shop.com domains, but not bananachool.com

Is this possible? Would I need access to the Zone file of bananaschool.com in order to make the domain mask / alias?

Thanks

Comment: The shop.com or bananaschool.com server also needs to listen for that acme.com domain. For that, you need webserver config access on bananaschool.com but no need to have access to that domain's DNS.

Comment: @JayMcTee Great, thanks, can you elaborate a bit more on the type of configuration required in nginx or Apache for this?